# iOS: Passing Array of Core Data entities from Obj-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, core-data

I have an Objective-C viewcontroller and within it I am trying to pass an array of core data entities (GroupToCustRelation) to a property of a Swift file.

In my Swift file I tried to do this:

```
var arrCustomers:[GroupToCustRelation] = []
```

I get a use of undeclared type error. Just starting on Swift so any help would be appreciated. How do I declare an empty array that is expecting Core Data entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your core data model classes are probably Objective-C then. To make them available to your Swift code you need to import those headers in your Swift Bridging Header. It should be called `[TargetName]-Bridging-Header.h`. If you didn’t let Xcode create this file when you first added Swift code to your project you can manually create such a header and enter it’s name in your targets build setting `Objective-C Bridging Header` which you will find in the `Swift Compiler - General` section.

Comment: ah, duh. I had just sent an email explaining how to expose Obj-C to Swiss to my co-workers...thanks!